# Set default value on Datetime field in symfony2 form

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.1

I have a form containing several fields. One of them is a Datetime field. How to define a default value for that field?

I've tried setting a value on the related entity, in controller, in constructor and __construct :

```
$myEntity = new MyEntity();
$myEntity->setMyDate(new \DateTime());
$form = $this->createForm(new AddMyEntity(), $myEntity);
```

Not working.

Tried to define the `$data` variable in the buildForm :

```
$builder->add('myDate', 'date', array(
    'format' => \IntlDateFormatter::SHORT,
    'input' => 'datetime',
    'widget' => 'single_text',
    'data' => new \DateTime("now"));
```

Not working either. 
Any ideas, Symfony2 community?

EDIT : Adding entity on demand of faost.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="myDate", type="datetime")
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 */
private $myDate;
```

Comment: Please show definition of the property "myDate" in class "MyEntity" and method "buildForm" of form type class "AddMyEntity".

Comment: The second part of my question is a extract of the buildForm method. And I'll add the entity part.

Comment: Your code is OK, it should work. But I take notice that you use datetime doctrine mapping type for "myDate" field so better use datetime field type in "AddMyEntity" class http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/datetime.html

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Set it in the entity constructor:

```php
class Entity
{
    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     */
    private $date;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->date = new \DateTime();
    }
}
```

Comment: As said in the question, if tried setting it as well as in the __construct as in the function MyEntity() without success.

Comment: Just to complete your suggestion, it actually works on simple types : text, ints and so on. It is not working on DateTime.

Comment: Hmm. I initialize `DateTime` objects in constructors and it works great. Probably something is wrong somewhere else in your app.

Comment: +1 @elnur: every time I search a Symfony2 related question lately, you've answered it. Thanks for that! :)

Comment: What did you do to get this working? I have the same problem. I'm using a form collection.

Comment: Based on: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/5095 and https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/6910 it seems there is a limitation with using default values set in entity constructors in form collections.

Comment: Upvoted because it's better to add defaults which should be persisted in the __construct

Comment: In constructor only assign variables to fields, nothing else, no condition, no instantiate, nothing. Constructors should be code free.

Answer (score 36):

Elnur's answer is correct and is perhaps the recommended one. But for completeness, an alternative way to set the default value for a date widget in a form is to specify the `data` key in the options array argument with an instance of DateTime.

```
$builder->add('myDate', 'date', array(
    'data' => new \DateTime()
));
```

**Note: This will overwrite the previously set datetime on every edit.**

Comment: This approach works only when adding new entry but fails when editing because it doesn't put database value but current time on the form

Comment: @MasindeMuliro Correct. I added this answer here because the question was the first result in Google and there was a scenario I had where tests wouldn't pass by simply instantiating in the constructor. If I recall what the edge case was, I'll add it to the answer.

Comment: Thank you! This was a better solution for me. I needed to default to the date the user edited the record, not the date it was first created in the database.

Comment: Instead of `date` as second parameter I had to set `DateType::class` and add the use statement of `Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateType`. Thank you very much

Answer (score 14):

This solution doesn't require modifying your entity object.

```
    $builder->add('myDate', DateTimeType::class, [
        'label' => 'My Date',
        'required' => false,
        'date_widget' => 'single_text',
        'time_widget' => 'single_text',
        'date_format' => 'dd/MM/yyyy'
    ]);

    $builder->get('myDate')->addModelTransformer(new CallbackTransformer(
        function ($value) {
            if(!$value) {
                return new \DateTime('now +1 month');
            }
            return $value;
        },
        function ($value) {
            return $value;
        }
    ));
```

This solution applies the behaviour to just this form, it does not couple this behaviour to the entity itself. You might have several forms that modify an entity with different required behaviours. Some require a default date, others don't.

Answer (score -8):

You can set the attributes to on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and defualt to current time stamp will update the current time stamp automatically without updating through query

```
`feildname` timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Comment: As said in the question above, I'm trying to set a default value in a form. Not in database. I need to suggest a default value to the user not.