# form use curremt datatime

Tags: forms, symfony, datetime

i have a form with a datetyoe field

```
  $builder->add('dataSpesa',DateType::class,array(
                    'data' => new \DateTime("now"),
                    'label'=>false,

                    'widget'=>'single_text',
                     'attr' => array('style' => 'width: 100%;margin-top:10px;',
                         'class' => 'js-datepicker'

                         )
                ))
```

now i want to use this form in edit form and use use the save datetime .. i try in this way but it don't work and i'm sure is the best way

```
   if($options['data']->getDataSpesa()){
            $data_spesa=$options['data']['dataSpesa']->getData(); ->>> syntax error  DON'T UNDERSTAND CORRECT WAY TO HAVE DATETIME VALUE
        }else{
            $data_spesa=new \DateTime("now");
        }


       ->add('dataSpesa',DateType::class,array(

                    'label'=>false,
                     'data'=>$data_spesa,  -> CORRECT WAY???
                    'widget'=>'single_text',
                     'attr' => array('style' => 'width: 100%;margin-top:10px;',
                         'class' => 'js-datepicker'

                         )
                ))
```

To better understand .. I use this form in 2 controller. In home page

```
 /**
     * @Route("/", name="homepage")
     */
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
               // crea nuovo
        $voce_costo = new VoceCosto();
        $form = $this->createForm(VoceCostoType::class, $voce_costo);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isvalid()) {
       return $this->render('default/add/vocecosto.html.twig', array(
                    'form' => $form->CreateView()
        ));
    }
```

in this i want the date is set by default as current date

In the other controller (edit controller)

```
    /**
     * @Route("/edit/{id_vocecosto}", name="edit_voce")
     */
    public function EditvoceCostoAction(Request $request,$id_vocecosto)
    {
               // crea nuovo
        $voce_costo =  $this->getDoctrine()
                ->getRepository('AppBundle:VoceCosto')
                ->find($id_vocecosto);
        $form = $this->createForm(VoceCostoType::class, $voce_costo);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isvalid()) {



        }
        return $this->render('default/edit/voce_costo.html.twig', array(
                    'form' => $form->CreateView()
        ));
    }
```

here i want that value is the data saved in database

Comment: Can you post the exact error you get? Do you want to set the current DateTime by default, or do you want to use the js-datepicker to set the time?

Comment: Attempted to call an undefined method named "getData" of class "DateTime".   i want to set current datetime when i am to create form , when i'm in the edit page form i want take date that is in datebase

Comment: I think you want to set the current DateTime in the constructor of your entity. And handle the editing in your form / controller.

Comment: yes is what i try to do

Comment: Did you set the constructor in your VoceCosto class/entity? Like https://stackoverflow.com/a/8714179/2354498