# Default Data in Create/Edit Mode in Symfony's Form using DateType

Tags: symfony

In a Symfony Form I have:

```
->add('fechalimite', DateType::class, [
  'format' => 'dMMMMyyyy',
  'data' => new \DateTime(),
])
```

Opening the form, I have in fechalimite field today's date: 15 December 2018. I can change the field, ex. 28 December 2018, and I submit the change in database without problem.

The problem come editing the form. When I edit the field take today's date, not 28 December 2018.

I am looking for a data default that does not remain in edit mode.

How can solve it?

Comment: Data option always overrides data of underlying object, so you should not use it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set default value on Datetime field in symfony2 form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8713200/set-default-value-on-datetime-field-in-symfony2-form)

Comment: Hi u_mulder, thanks for your answer. Then, is it possible to condition the ->add() of the form depending on whether the path is edit or create? which would be an alternative and possible solution to what I'm looking for.

Comment: U_mulder, in  "Set default value on Datetime field in symfony2 form" there is a syntax problem. It has nothing to do with my question

Answer (score 1):

You can use your entity constructor to set the default value like this:

```
class YourEntity {
  private $fechalimite;

  public function __construct()
  {
     $this->fechalimite = new \DateTime();
  } 
}
```

That will set the default value when you create a new entity.

Comment: Thanks Rodmar, I try your solution and works fine too, and It's more elegant than mine for what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution to discriminate between create and edit:

```
$formMapper;

    if ($this->isCurrentRoute('create')) {
    $formMapper
        ->add('fechalimite', DateType::class, [
          'format' => 'dMMMMyyyy',
          'data' => new \DateTime(),
        ])
        ;
    } else {
    $formMapper
        ->add('fechalimite', DateType::class, [
          'format' => 'dMMMMyyyy',
        ])
        ;
    }
```